# Autoplay On This Link Slider - Working Example

Tags: jquery, slider, carousel, autoplay

Autoplay Custom Slider.

Currently I have the slider working so when a link is clicked the slider moves to the next slide, or jumps to the slide you have chosen. This all works fine.

I would like the slider to autoplay after a set time.

I will still need each link to be clickable and take you to the relevant slide.

Once a link has been clicked the autoplay feature will need to disable so slides can be viewed for however long the user decides.

I have tried a few solutions but nothing seems to work, can this be done?

Thanks

Please see link to working example http://www.designashby.co.uk/slider.php

Comment: Either your HTML or jQuery (or both) is incomplete. Please post a complete, functional example.

Comment: I have removed the code and replaced this with a working example, without autoplay, seen here --> http://www.designashby.co.uk/slider.php

Answer (score 0):

To have a timer, you will want to do something like:

```
setInterval(5000, function(){
  $('#list-links li a').trigger('click');
});
```

After 5 seconds, that link will be clicked and your slides will move.